# R - heatmap.2: reorder rows and columns

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I generated a heatmap using heatmap.2 of the gplots package:

```
library(gplots)
abc <-read.csv(file="abc.txt", header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
abcm<-as.matrix(abc)
def <-read.csv(file="def.txt", header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
defm<-as.matrix(def)
mean <-read.csv(file="mean.txt", header=T, sep="\t", dec=".")
meanm<-as.matrix(mean)
distance.row = dist(as.matrix(def), method = "euclidean")
cluster.row = hclust(distance.row, method = "average")
distance.col = dist(t(as.matrix(abc)), method = "euclidean")
cluster.col = hclust(distance.col, method = "average")
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(n = 299)

heatmap.2(meanm, trace="none", dendrogram="both", Rowv=as.dendrogram(cluster.row), Colv=as.dendrogram(cluster.col), margins = c(7,7), col=my_palette)
```

with two different clustering methods for each dendrogram.

[image: heatmap]

Now I want to reorder the objects, so that the green squares form a diagonal. How do I do that?

EDIT: my sample input here

```
structure(c(1, 0.6798, 0.6604, 0.7101, 0.6771, 0.6725, 0.6696, 
0.6548, 0.676, 0.6811, 0.6798, 1, 0.656, 0.6763, 0.8163, 0.781, 
0.7811, 0.6503, 0.7811, 0.855, 0.6604, 0.656, 1, 0.6532, 0.6498, 
0.6459, 0.6455, 0.7532, 0.6521, 0.6536, 0.7101, 0.6763, 0.6532, 
1, 0.672, 0.669, 0.6669, 0.6517, 0.6748, 0.6786, 0.6771, 0.8163, 
0.6498, 0.672, 1, 0.7828, 0.7838, 0.6441, 0.7736, 0.8227, 0.6725, 
0.781, 0.6459, 0.669, 0.7828, 1, 0.8361, 0.6447, 0.7574, 0.7796, 
0.6696, 0.7811, 0.6455, 0.6669, 0.7838, 0.8361, 1, 0.638, 0.7566, 
0.7772, 0.6548, 0.6503, 0.7532, 0.6517, 0.6441, 0.6447, 0.638, 
1, 0.6563, 0.6459, 0.676, 0.7811, 0.6521, 0.6748, 0.7736, 0.7574, 
0.7566, 0.6563, 1, 0.7778, 0.6811, 0.855, 0.6536, 0.6786, 0.8227, 
0.7796, 0.7772, 0.6459, 0.7778, 1), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp6", "sp7", "sp8", 
    "sp9", "sp10"), c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp6", 
    "sp7", "sp8", "sp9", "sp10")))
```

Comment: Can you include sample data? Easiest may be to use `dput()` with a subset of your data.

Comment: @LukeC see my edits!

Comment: Thanks @rororo- I think for completeness you would need to include the `cluster.row` and `cluster.col` so that users could actually plot the heatmap as you have done. However, I might be misunderstanding you- you want to reorder your rows and columns so that you get a diagonal. Wouldn't that break your dendrogram? For sp 4, 1, 8, and 3 it wouldn't necessarily matter (just flip that branch) but for sp 9, 6, and 7, I can't see a dendrogram configuration that would allow the diagonal. See the `Rowv` and `Colv` arguments for `heatmap.2` for more info. If I'm not understanding you I apologize!

Comment: oh I totally overlooked that! sp9 is clustering differently :/ but still, how would I flip the branches, so that at least _most_ of the items are aligning?

Comment: Maybe try `reorder.dendrogram`- check out the example in the help for that function, it looks like it might do what you need.

Comment: thank you for that hint! adding the _arbritrary_ values 10:1 makes it much better. The documentation for that parameter is pretty vague though... If you answer my question officially I'd be delighted!

Comment: Thanks, but I think you should answer! I have no idea how you actually sorted it out, and I think a complete answer showing the solution that you are happy with would probably be the most helpful for anyone else with a similar question down the line. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `reorder.dendrogram` flips the branches.

```
reorder(as.dendrogram(cluster.col), 10:1)
reorder(as.dendrogram(cluster.row), 10:1)
```

used in

```
heatmap.2(meanm, trace="none", dendrogram="both",
Rowv=reorder(as.dendrogram(cluster.row), 10:1),
Colv=reorder(as.dendrogram(cluster.col), 10:1),
margins = c(7,7), breaks=breaks,col=hm.colors, na.color="white",
main="mean(AAI+ANI)", xlab="AAI clustering", ylab="ANI clustering", srtCol=45)
```